# Graphql returning nested type

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, graphql

I'm new to graphql.js and I am trying trying to build a nested graphql type.

Currently I have a `GameStatistic` type and I want to have a `Statistic` type have has two fields with GameStatistic type.

```
const gameStatisticType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'GameStatistic',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    wagered: { type: GraphQLFloat },
    profit: { type: GraphQLFloat },
  },
});

exports.Type = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Statistic',
  fields: {
    dice: new GraphQLObjectType(gameStatisticType),
    wheel: new GraphQLObjectType(gameStatisticType),
  },
});
```

But it keeps giving the error of `"The type of Statistic.wheel must be Output Type but got: undefined."`and `"The type of Statistic.dice must be Output Type but got: undefined."`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- don't call `GraphQLObjectType` again, you already have an instance
- put the type in the `.type` property of an object describing the field

```
exports.Type = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Statistic',
  fields: {
    dice: { type: gameStatisticType },
    wheel: { type: gameStatisticType },
  },
});
```

Comment: Ah that what it is! Thank you!